# TaskCanceledException after 100 seconds

Tags: c#, backgroundworker, dotnet-httpclient, multitasking

I use a backgroundworker in my asp.net core web-service. In this backgroundworker I use:

```
var response = await client.PostAsync(baseUri + "/api/worker/" + Id , content);
```

This works fine if the call takes less than 100 seconds, but if it takes longer, then it thows a
TaskCanceldException.

So how can I increase this timeout?

Comment: `client.Timeout = 500*1000` for 500 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the client var is HttpClient, you can set its Timeout property.

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
```

Here is the [official doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout?view=netcore-3.1)